# Undefined is not a function (redux action/ react native)

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

I want to dispatch an action but I always get the error message "undefined is not a function".
The Errormessage is provided [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLQLb.png)

This is the React Component I am using.
Thank you very much!

```
class CourseCard extends React.Component {
constructor(props){
  super(props);
};
upId(){
this.props.kursidupdate(this.props.id);
}
render() {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.upId.bind(this)} style={{flex: 1}}>
      <Text>{this.props.headline}</Text>
        <Text>Morgen</Text>
        <Text>Mehr</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
);
}
}
const mapDispatchToProps= dispatch=>{
 return{
  kursidupdate:(kursid)=>
  dispatch(kursidupdate(kursid))
 };
 };
 export default CourseCard;
```

Comment: if i am not wrong then you are not connecting your component to redux store using connect function.

Comment: you are absolutely right. Sorry for that dumb question. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You should add the connect to your component:

```
export default connect(mapDispatchToProps)(CourseCard);
```